# How to set ordering and number of items for each item in filter list?

Tags: django

How to set ordering and number of items for each item in filter list?

```
class Category(models.Model):
category = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

Class Question(TimeStampedModel):
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='question_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
question = models.TextField(_('Question Text'))

Category.objects.filter(category__in=['Sport', 'History']).values_list('question_set',flat=True).order_by('?')[:3] 
<QuerySet [6, 7, 3]>
```

I need result like:

```
<QuerySet [1, 3, 2, 7, 11, 9]>
```

Comment: Since you use `[:3]` you will retrieve the first three elements.

Comment: Also your have to specify the needed order in `order_by` part.